# Como exibir itens de um ArrayList por um vetor?

Tags: java

Bolei um código aqui, está assim:

```
class Main {
    Lista lista = new Lista();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        i = 0;
        String[] vetorExibir;
        lista.exibicao(vetorExibir = new String[lista.lista.size()]);
        while (i < vetorExibir.length) {
            System.out.println(vetorExibir[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
class Lista {
    ArrayList<String> lista;
    public Lista() {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public String[] exibicao(String[] vetorExibir) {
        int i = 0;
        vetorExibir = new String[lista.size()];
        while (i < lista.size()) {
            vetorExibir[i] = lista.get(i);
        } return vetorExibir;
    }
}
```

Considerando que o ArrayList já tenha dados.
Ele não funciona, não exibe nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vários probleminhas no seu código, a começar com o statement:

```
 lista.exibicao(vetorExibir = new String[lista.lista.size()]);
```

nesse momento, lista.size() == 0, ou seja, você tá criando um array de tamanho zero.

o outro problema é que no método exibicao(), você muda o valor do parâmetro, e isso não será refletido externamente em JAVA. Pro seu código funcionar, você precisa fazer assim:

```
  String[] vetorExibir = lista.exibicao(...);
```

assim você usa o vetor retornado pelo metodo.

Sugiro que descarte o seu código e use o que a API já oferece:

```
  ArrayList<String> arrayList = getArrayListPopulated();
  String[] vetorExibir = arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
```

Comment: Mas por que `lista.size()` seria 0? Se existem itens no ArrayList, ele tem um tamanho maior que zero, certo?

De qualquer maneira, usarei sua sugestão. Ela ficaria no método principal?

Comment: você não populou a o ArrayList 'lista' em lugar algum, por isso que é zero naquele momento.